# Durrett 2.2.2. Do we need zero mean assumption in a $L^2$ weak law to certain dependent sequence?

Tags: probability-theory, law-of-large-numbers

In [Durrett's textbook](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf), Exercise 2.2.2 states that

[image]

My two questions are

> Q1: ***do we need to assume $EX_n = 0?$***
>
> Q2: Is there any non-independent example to illustrate this generalization?

Now I skectch my proof:

I show it converges in $L^2$ by expanding $E(\frac{X_1 + \cdots X_n}{n})^2$ and then observing that it's smaller than

$\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{|i-j|\text{is not large}} r(|i-j|)$ + $\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{|i-j|\text{is large}} r(|i-j|).$

Then the first finite term is controlled by $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and the second term is controlled by the decay of $r(k).$

Since every random variable in the above computations is quadratic (i.e. $X_i X_j$), I don't think we need to assume $EX_n = 0?$ Does it play a role on the existence of the function $r(k)?$

Answer (score 1):

I have a satisfactory explanation to Question 1 now, but nothing for Question 2 yet:

I go back to consider any independent sequence of random variables $\{ X_n \}_n$ and find that $EX_n X_m = EX_n EX_m.$ I think this gives a reason that why the exercise requires $EX_n = 0$ so that the function $r(k)$ may exist naturally.

Actually, if $\{ X_n \}$ is non-independent with non-zero means, just consider $Y_n = X_n - EX_n$ and require the condition $EY_nY_m \leq r(n-m).$